# Why is Puppeteer not loading images from my LibreNMS dashboard widget graphs?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, screenshot

I'm very new to all of this, so please forgive my ignorance.  To work around the lack of reporting in LibreNMS, I've decided to pull screenshots from the initially loaded dashboard once authentication is complete using Puppeteer and headless chrome.  The screenshots appear to be loading just fine, with the exception of a bandwidth graph and a session count graph (see image at the end).  I've seen some other people having a similar issue (not LibreNMS), and it seems that forcing Puppeteer to wait for a set amount of time/network idle/certain events to occur have fixed their problem.  No amount of waiting has allowed these graphs to appear in my screenshot.  While others were experiencing a blank space where the image ought to appear, mine show a broken link icon in the top left corner of the element border.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?  Here is the script I'm working with:

command: node screenshot.js http://localhost

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = process.argv[2];
const delay = (milliseconds) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));

if (!url) {
    throw "Please provide a URL as the first argument";
}
async function run () {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil:['domcontentloaded'] });
        await page.type('#username', 'username');
        await page.type('#password', 'password');
        // click and wait for navigation
        await page.click('#login');
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' });
        // delay(5000);
        await page.screenshot({path: 'report.png'});
        browser.close();
}
run();
```

HTML Code of one of the problem graphs

```
<div class="dashboard-graph">
    <a href="graphs/id=6/type=port_bits/from=1696604049/to=1696618449">
        <img class="minigraph-image" width="390.46360000000004" height="355.6666" src="graph.php?id=6&amp;from=1696604049&amp;to=1696618449&amp;width=390.46360000000004&amp;height=355.6666&amp;type=port_bits&amp;legend=yes&amp;absolute=1">
    </a>
</div>
```

Tried using page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }) to make sure no further network traffic is present before the screenshot happens.

Also tried waiting an arbitrary amount of time (delay(5000);) to no avail.

Same with page.waitForSelector('widget_body_9', {visible: true}) in case the widget on the dashboard needed more time. I don't believe it is a timing issue, but I could be wrong.

[Broken graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvA6g.png)

Comment: add {headless: false} and check the network tab, it sounds like the image request failed

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I apologize, but I'm not sure where I would be adding {headless: false} to, or what network tab you're talking about.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, `await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})` - for debugging so you can see what's happening

Comment: Think I figured out where to run it (puppeteer.launch({headless: false}), but now I've got an error that pops up:

[40268:40268:1006/200519.193337:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[40268:40268:1006/200519.194988:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting

Comment: I'm talking about running it on your pc so you can see what's happening with the images (you can't run it that way on your server)

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  I've got Puppeteer running on a headless Ubuntu VM right now.  I don't really have a good way of replicating that setup on my Windows PC unfortunately.  I do know that simply browsing to the webserver from Chrome on Windows populates those graphs.  Maybe I've got some investigating to do on my Ubuntu install.

Comment: Managed to run Puppeteer with the {headless:false} piece after installing xvfb and giving the script a display to attach to, but the result is the same.

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear. you want to run the script locally in non-headless mode so you can see what's happening and diagnose the issue with the images. If you can't run it locally then ignore my comment.

Comment: Went ahead and got Puppeteer installed locally on my Windows PC, ran the same script (headless), and everything is working as expected! I've decided not to pursue any further troubleshooting on the Ubuntu install.  Windows with Puppeteer will work just fine as a work around. Thank you for your time pguardiario. –